# How to Update and Delete the required recored of a table usning Core Data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I am learning the core data 
How to delete and update the data using core data. I have worked on upload and fetch. I need to write the methods for delete and update. Please tell me how to update and delete a recode using core data.

Below I have written code for upload and fetch data from table using core data.

```
-(void)uploadData
{
    Employee *empObj=(Employee *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];


    empObj.empId=[NSNumber numberWithInt:12345];
    empObj.empSalary=[NSNumber numberWithInt:25000];

    empObj.empName=@"Venu";
    empObj.empDesignation=@"Programmer";
    empObj.empExp=@"2 Years";

    if ([self.managedObjectContext hasChanges] )
    {
        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
    }

}
-(void)fetchData
{
    NSEntityDescription *empEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    // Setup the fetch request
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSArray *fatherArray=[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

    [request setEntity:empEntity];

    NSArray *empArray=[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

    for (int i=0; i<[empArray count]; i++) 
    {
        printf("\n=================================Recored== %d==================================== ",i);

        Employee *empObj=[empArray objectAtIndex:i];
        printf("\n obj.empName========= %s",[empObj.empName UTF8String]);
        printf("\n obj.empDesignation========= %s",[empObj.empDesignation UTF8String]);
        printf("\n obj.empExp========= %s",[empObj.empExp UTF8String]);
        printf("\n obj.empId========= %d",[empObj.empId intValue]);
        printf("\n obj.empSalary========= %d",[empObj.empSalary intValue]);
        printf("\n============================================================================= ");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am doing a project which involved in Core Data, and I would
like to share something with you about it.

It is a clear that before you delete or update a record you need
to retrieve that record.

Use the employee with empId 12345 as an example,

a)Delete

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];  
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@:@"Employee"                                                
                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];   


NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"empId = %d", 12345]];  
[request setPredicate:pred];


NSArray *empArray=[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];  
[request release];

if ([empArray count] > 0){
    Employee *employee = [empArray objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:employee];
    [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
}
```

b) update

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@:@"Employee"    
                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];   

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"empId = %d", 12345]];
[request setPredicate:pred];

NSArray *empArray=[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
[request release];

if ([empArray count] > 0){
    Employee *employee = [empArray objectAtIndex:0];

    employee.empSalary=[NSNumber numberWithInt:45000];

    employee.empName=@"John";
    employee.empDesignation=@"Analysist";
    employee.empExp=@"4 Years";

    [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
}
```

Comment: What happens here? Is it smart enough to save "only" that changed record or does it update all items in empArray?

Answer (score 0):

After a successful fetch-request, you can delete your objects simply by asking the managed objectcontext to delete them:

```
for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in items) {
    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
    DebugLog(@"%@ object deleted",entityDescription);
}
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    DebugLog(@"Error deleting %@ - error:%@",entityDescription,error);
}
```

Updating is done in a similar way, fetch the object desired, change the value, and save the context.